# if we use CTE in sql Query will it work when we use the query in Crystal report?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I'm wondering if i used CTE in a query will i be able to create a crystal report ? 
also can i use the CTE with case when function ?

Comment: i can't risk it since I'm not allowed to create a testing report in the place where i work , i can only create the report once I'm 100% sure

Comment: Create it in a view and try it, I agree with @dbajtr, you will have to test any query before releasing in the application, it is standard procedure

Comment: You aren't *allowed to test*? That sounds like a bad policy...

Comment: Hello. Even if some policy prohibits this in production, is there a reason why you would be prohibited from trying something on your own machine? Also, the "have you tried it?" goes against the most recent "Be Nice" post from the Stack Overflow management. Let's get with it, guys. Shahad: Yes, you can use CTE's just fine in any SQL Query, and it will work fine in a report. The report only cares about output, not the nature of your query. BTW, the blog post link from the management is LITERALLY displayed on this page as we write these comments.

Comment: Most report tools will pass the query to the DB engine, in which case all syntax will work.  If they have to pass through an ODBC driver rather than one native to the DB there may be limitations.  As implied by @Ven a good practice is to create a view on the DB and the report writer then calls a simple query.

Comment: I agree with creating a view. In addition to simplifying what you use in your report, it will also improve security of your database by abstracting away the guts of your actual table. And re: "not allowed to create a testing report" - I will caution that, especially when working with reports, this is an excellent way to accidentally end up doing very bad things to your data.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the report will work with a CTE, even if the CTE includes a CASE function.